# Get colum from image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need a script that detects the column of the image that I click on to execute a script that sort the values ​​of that column. I have an image per column that works as a button, which when clicked sort the values ​​of that column starting from row 3. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pETAL.jpg).

I have a function for each column, but what I am looking for is to optimize everything in a single code that detects the column where the image that I clicked is on and based on that it works on that column.
This is the code I have for each column, just changing the ranges for each one
Note: The embedded image is on my drive

```
function ORDERJ() {
  
  Lec.getRange('J6').activate();
  if(Lec.getRange('J2').getValue() == "" && Lec.getRange('J6:J').getValues().filter(String).length > 0)
  { Lec.getRange('J2:J').setValue(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()).setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm')}
  if(Lec.getRange('J3').getValue() == "")
  { Lec.getRange ('J2').clearContent();}
  ORDENAR();
}

function ORDERK() {
  
  Lec.getRange('K6').activate();
  if(Lec.getRange('K2').getValue() == "" && Lec.getRange('K6:K').getValues().filter(String).length > 0)
  { Lec.getRange('K2').setValue(new Date().toLocaleTimeString()).setNumberFormat('h":"mm" "am/pm')}
  if(Lec.getRange('K3').getValue() == "")
  { Lec.getRange ('K2').clearContent();}
  ORDENAR();
}
```

Comment: I would consider using checkboxes and an onEdit trigger.  The event object will tell you which cell was checked